# Regex - finding strings between signs

Tags: regex

I was trying to solve this by myself but there are only solutions for cases like that:

"text" "text2" "text3"

I need to write a pattern which takes strings starting with '-' sign, expected result is shown below:

Input:

```
-something/3443/kk-somethingelse/111/333/zz
-text/ff/33/33/zz
```

Output:

```
1. something/3443/kk
2. somethingelse/111/333/zz
3. text/ff/33/33/zz
```

as individual grups.

Thanks in advance and sorry I couldnt manage that.

Comment: What engine/language are you using?

Comment: [Regex reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618)

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern, with `global` flag:

```
-([^-\s]+)
```

[Demo link](https://regex101.com/r/eE0uT4/3)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eE0uT4/1

Answer (score 0):

I would exclude line breaks as well:

```
-([^-\r\n]+)
```